# How does one go about iterating through kmem_caches?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I'm trying to do something that seems like it should be exceptionally simple, iterating through the kmem_cache objects held in `kmalloc_caches` to print their names.  This invariably ends in a kernel panic.  My C is very rusty, so if I'm misunderstanding something, I would appreciate any illumination.  I added the following function:

```
void *print_cachenames(void) {
    struct kmem_cache *k;
k = kmalloc_caches[0];
    printk(KERN_INFO "680: k[0] name: %s\n", k->name);
}
```

to mm/slub.c.  All it does is try to print the name of the first kmem_cache object in the array.  What's causing it to blow up?

Comment: Wish I knew the answer to this, sounds like an interesting question...

Answer (score 0):

Your function is declared as returning a `void *`, and it's failing to return anything at all. I'm not sure where your function is being called from, but chances are that it's supposed to return something...

Answer (score 0):

`kmalloc_caches[0]` appears to be unused.  In general you should check if the pointer you read from the cache is NULL or not before trying to use it:

```
void print_cachenames(void) {
        struct kmem_cache *k = kmalloc_caches[0];

        if (k && k->name)
                printk(KERN_INFO "680: k[0] name: %s\n", k->name);
        else 
                printk(KERN_INFO "680: k[0] == %p, has no name\n");
}
```